# Incompatibility between subxt_signer and subxt

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, rust, pallet-contracts, subxt

https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/subxt/examples/tx_basic.rs

I want to call a function in my substrate pallet. I am using the

- **substrate-node-template**
- **subxt**
- **subxt_signer**

```
use subxt::{OnlineClient, PolkadotConfig};
use subxt_signer::sr25519::dev;

#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "./src/artifacts/metadata.scale")]
pub mod polkadot {}
{
   // ...

   let account = dev::alice();
   let call = polkadot::tx().template_module().do_something(32);
   api.tx()
      .sign_and_submit_then_watch_default(&call, &account)
      .await
      .unwrap();
      
  // ...
}
```

but sign_and_submit_then_watch_default is giving error for &account. This is the error that I get

```
the trait bound `subxt_signer::sr25519::Keypair: subxt::tx::Signer<PolkadotConfig>` is not satisfied
the trait `subxt::tx::Signer<PolkadotConfig>` is not implemented for `subxt_signer::sr25519::Keypair`
```

I have tried using sp_core and changing versions but nothing seems to work.

My current versions are:

```
subxt = "0.31.0"
subxt-signer = "0.31.0"
```

Comment: Could you run a `cargo tree -i subxt` and a `cargo tree -i subxt-signer` in your example and report back the result? The likely explanation for this sort of mismatch is that the versions of `subxt` and `subxt-signer` are not in fact both 0.31.

Comment: @jsdw 

For both, the versions are the same.


subxt-signer v0.31.0 || subxt v0.31.0

Comment: Aha, I forgot about that "subxt" feature flag :)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to the problem. In my case, I needed to make changes to Cargo.toml.

```
subxt-signer = { version = "0.31.0", features = ["subxt"]}
```

I had to add **features = ["subxt"]** to make it work.